# CPA, Cost per action with Drupal

Tags: files

I am trying to find out what are set of modules, or what can be done to emulate a CPA system on Drupal?

if we look at for example sharecash.org, a user upload a file. for distribution, a user click on a file to Download, which sends him a pop up to fill in a survey. there are normally various surveys options and those surveys are geo-targeted. If I am in the US, I will have a US related survey to fill, the same applies if I am in other countries.

now after a user finished fill in a survey, there is a callback url which is redirected to the user to unlock the file for the use to download. well I still don't get the picture clearly, if they use cookies or Callback url, but I will stick to the later one.

I am trying to find how can I do the same thing on drupal?

so far, the important part is a user click on a file, he fills in a survey on an external site, the external site redirect the user to the drupal page with an unlocking url/code whatever mechanism. I will be grateful if you can please clarify this and how it can be achieved.

regards,

Comment: The mechanism I am talking about is called Content Locking, which prevent the user to download the file unless he fills in a survey.

Comment: there is a sandbox project to create a private link. Not sure how far it has reached. http://drupal.org/sandbox/bradjmsu/1370844